# mysql stored procedure declare error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, declare

I don't really get the error ...

i put the declare statement right after begin. i usually do a lot of MS SQL so i am not that practiced in mysql syntax. please help me out

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddEntry2`(IN `inDate` DATE, IN `inUser` INT, IN `inComment` TEXT, IN `inStart` INT, IN `inEnd` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE commID UNSIGNED;
INSERT IGNORE INTO dimcomment (comment) values (inComment);
SELECT commID := MAX(id) 
                          FROM  dimcomment 
                          WHERE comment = inComment;

INSERT INTO factentry (FKDate, FKUser, FKComment,FKStart,FKEnd,FKAbsence)
VALUES (
        inDate,
        inUser,
        commID,
        inStart,
        inEnd,
        1
    );
END //
```

Error I get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED;
INSERT IGNORE INTO dimcomment (comment) values (inComment);
SELECT c' at line 3
```

well i changed UNSIGNED to INT and Error Message changed:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= MAX(id) 
                          FROM     dimcomment 
                      ' at line 5
```

Seems like i cannot set via SELECT VAR := VALUE ?

Comment: What _is_ the error you get?

Comment: Apart from your syntax problems: The `INSERT` ... `SELECT MAX(id)` sequence will break under load. Use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: That looks like you should be using `INT` instead of `UNSIGNED` in the declaration.  `INT UNSIGNED` probably works - I don't think I've ever tried.

Comment: Ah you posted the error. That should be it then - use `INT` or `INT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: check post, i edited the new error message